# Derive a formula for the volume of the wedge in terms of the constants $a$, $b$, $c$.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Derive a formula for the volume of the wedge in terms of the constants $a$, $b$, $c$.

[image]

Seeing a similar triangle, I see that $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{c}{b}$, $y$ being the distance from the $a$ line to the edge. And now $y=\frac{bx}{c}$

The area for the cross section is now $A=\frac{b}{2c}x^2$. I integrate:

$\frac{b}{2c} \int_{0}^{a}x^2dx=\frac{ba^2}{6c}$

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to get the volume from the point $a$ to the cross section?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I see the way I'm doing it now is not working

Comment: Is $x$ the vertical length of the wedge, or is it the distance from the origin?

Comment: It is the vertical height from the $a$ line, parallel to $c$

Comment: Why are you integrating from x=0 to x=a? You would need to integrate from z=0 to z=a, so try finding the area as a function of z.

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting it to the 3rd dimension. Another similar triangle?